# How to model mutliple Many-To-Many relationships that create a circle

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I am looking for direction on how to model something for a database.    What I am trying to model is this:  I have a list of Services.  Each service can be made available to a list of countries.  Each Service, that is avialable to that Country may or may not actually be being used in that country, so I need to capture that too.

I model this as three tables.  CountriesTable, ServicesTable and Services_CountriesTable.  The Services_CountriesTable has a column for the Services ID, Country ID and Is_Being_Used, which is aa boolean for whether or not the country is using the Service.

On the application,  the user can edit a page about the Service and they can pick from a list of check boxes, for Countries that the services is available in.  When the pick countries from the available Countries list, the UI then adds those countries to a second list of checkboxes, that the user can tick to say the country is actually using the service.

This works fine.  But, I was asked to include an option, in the list of Countries, for "Worldwide" which is comprised of multiple countries (I can also see other options be requested to have added that would be similar).  So, the user can just select Worldwide as the countries the Service is available in.

This causes problems for the Services_CountriesTable table, as I can no longer use it to also track which countries are actually using the service.  Since I currently store that value in the relationship in the Country_Service table (Country_ID, Service_ID, Is_Using).  But, if I introduce Worldwide, I can't use this because the Country_ID would be for Worldwide, but what would Is_Using mean?  Some countries might be using it, but others may not

I could make a set of four tables (Services, Countries, Services_Countries_Available, Services_Countries_Using) but they would all be joined in a circle, which doesn't seem right.  Is there a better option to model this?

Comment: You could consider "Worldwide" as just another country.  You can also associate the Service with all the countries individually, assuming you don't list 100s of countries.

Comment: yes, but that would ignore the requirement for denoting which countries are using the Service.  For example, maybe Service A is available Worldwide, but only being used in three countries.  How would you denote which countries are using it?